# Replacing order of infinite sum and limit with some weaker form of dominated convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory, limits

Let $f(x,n)$ be some positive function of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb N$
Using dominated convergence theorem, with $\mu(A)=|A|$ as the measure, we can prove that if $f(x,n)<g(n)$ for any $x$, and $g(n)$ is integrable in $\mu$ (i.e. absolutly convergent), then $\sum\limits_i\!\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\!f(x,i)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\!\sum\limits_i\!f(x,i)$.

Assume that $\sum\limits_i f(x,i)<c$ for any $x>0$. Say that for any $\delta>0$ there exists some $m$ (we can also assume that for any $m$ there exists some $\delta>0$) and integrable  $g(n)$ such that for any $|x|<\delta$ and any $n<m$ we get $f(x,n)<g(n)$ (note that $g$ is not a function of $m$), and $\sum\limits_i\!g_m(i)<2c$. Is it still true that $\sum\limits_i\!\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\!f(x,i)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\!\sum\limits_i\!f(x,i)$?

Edit:
We can assume the following:

$f$ is bounded for any $x,i$

$f$ is uniformly continuous for any fixed $i$

$f$ is a function from $(0,1)\mathbb\times{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

For any $i,x$, $f(x,i)\leq\frac{1}{i}$

Comment: In your sums, the summation variable ought to be $n$, not $i$. With that, note that $$\sum_n \lim_{x\to 0} f(x,n) = \sum_{n \leqslant m} \lim_{x\to 0} f(x,n) + \sum_{n> m} \lim_{x\to 0} f(x,n).$$ The first sum is finite.

Comment: Yup, completely messed up the question. It should be "for any $\delta>0$ there exists some $m$, otherwise the question is,like you said, trivial. Thank you for your comment, I changed the question accordingly.

Comment: Still the same, you just choose a $\delta$ first. Then take the appropriate $m$ and split. The second sum is dominated, and the first finite.

Comment: @DanielFischer OK, so I've editted the question. The bound is on the head of the sum, and not the infinite tail, and that's the problem. I do know that the tail converge, then it should be as small as I want for any large enough n and small enough $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeating the functions you can get rid over the condition $|f(x,i)|\le \frac1i$.

A counterexample:
let 
$$
h(x,n)=\begin{cases} \frac{1-nx}2 & 0<x\le \frac1n \\
0 & \frac1n\le x<1 \end{cases}
$$
and let
$$
f(x,1) = h(x,1),
$$
$$
f(x,i) = \frac1{2^{n-1}} \big(h(x,n+1)-h(x,n) \big) \quad \text{for} \quad
2^{n-1}< i \le 2^n.
$$
Then $f(x,i)$ is obviously bounded and continuous and $|f(x,i)|\le\frac1{2^n}\le\frac1i$. Moreover, $h_n\le h_{n-1}$, so for $2^{n-1}\le k\le 2^n$ we have
$$
h(x,n) \le \sum_{i=1}^k f(x,i) \le h(x,n-1).
$$
Then $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty f(x,i)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}h(x,n)=0$ pointwise, and
$\lim\limits_{x\to0} f(x,i)=\begin{cases}\frac12 & i=1 \\ 0 & i>1\end{cases}$.
So,
$$ 
\lim_{x\to0} \sum_{i=1}^\infty f(x,i) = 0
\ne
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lim_{x\to0} f(x,i) = \frac12.
$$